# JPA Event to delete Entity from DB fired by deletion of an Entity from another Persistence Unit

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, persistence, jpa-2.0, cascading-deletes

in the application that I am working on, somebody split the domain objects into different persistence units. The connection between tables from different persistence units is made based on columns containing the ID for instance:

```
TableA             TableB
ID:Int             ID:int
Field1             TableA_ID:Int
Field2             ...  
...
```

The `TableA_ID` is just a plain int, no constraints are enforced on it. Now I need to delete the parent entity (let's say `TableA` but also all the connected `TableB`s entities). In case of a foreign key relation, this would be a plain and simple CASCADE delete. **But in this case, how should I proceed?** A DB Trigger - I would like to keep everything in JPA.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have DAOs for TableA and TableB you can achieve a solution writing a service method using collaboration in this manner (just a sample):

```
@Repository
class TableADAO {
  void deleteById(int id) {
    // perform deletion where TableA.ID == id
  }
}

@Repository
class TableBDAO {
  void deleteTableAChildren(int id) {
    // perform deletion where TableA_ID == id
  }
}

@Service
class MyService {
  private TableADAO tableADAO;
  private TableBDAO tableBDAO;

  @Transactional
  // Annotating as transactional to prevent
  // invalid data
  void deleteTableACascade(int idTableA) {
    tableBDAO.deleteTableAChildren(idTableA);
    tableADAO.deleteById(idTableA);
  }
}
```

Is it a plausible solution?

Comment: thank you for your response, yes, this would be the most common sense approach. Unfortunately the persistence level is written in a very generic fashion, so composing DAOs can be at least complicated. This is why I was looking more for a solution based on triggers/ events.

Comment: ok, but I think that this logic can be applicated in every situation: instead of using dao just do raw SQL in service method, I think @Transactional() is the point of interest, not the way you use to delete data. my 2 cents

Comment: I finally solved the issue by using CDI events. Thank you for your support.